# 'Lots' as a noun or quantifier with ellipsis?

Tags: nouns, quantifiers, parts-of-speech

I'd like the opinion of the community on the status of *lots* when used in the following:

> Your tutor will be an experienced teacher from whom you can learn lots.

Is *lots* here still a quantifier or does it become the noun/object?

Comment: As you imply, it's a relict from the noun phrase 'lots of stuff / good stuff / facts / information ...'. As such, it's a part-(ex-quantifier), and it doesn't really make sense to try to rigorously define its POS. You could argue that it fills an obvious noun slot (learn facts [ about] ...) (but one doesn't learn/become familiar with 'lots' in the same sense one does with 'facts/words/names...') or that it modifies 'learn'. Some might label it an 'adverbial objective', distinguishing form and function (a noun used as [if it were] an adverb), but the form / function debate is unresolved..

Comment: Normally "lots" takes an _of_ pp as complement as in "Lots of errors were made". "Lots" is a noun, not a determiner, so there is no question of there being any 'fusion' here of determiner and head. That being the case, I'd say this is probably a case of ellipsis, where the _of_ complement of "lots" is ellipted. We understand it to mean something like "lots of things".

Comment: By comparison with [*(He) can learn **a lot** from (her)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+learn+lots%2Ccan+learn+a+lot&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20learn%20lots%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20learn%20a%20lot%3B%2Cc0), He can learn **lots** from her* is virtually non-existent (and it doesn't sound at all good to me).

Answer (score -1):

The word 'lots' in this sentence is, for me, a quantifier with the unspoken words 'of things' implied after it. Interestingly if the sentence had 'a lot' at the end instead of 'lots' the phrase 'a lot' would seem to be more formally correct and definitely to be a noun; however it would still imply 'of things' in the same way. The words 'lot' and 'lots' can be nouns in their own right but have a different meaning, think 'There are 20 lots in this auction' or 'The field has been divided into several lots'

Comment: '_A lot_ would definitely seem to be a noun'? And in 'I like him a lot'?